# How to estimate magnetizing inductance and core resistance of transformer based only on material properties and dimensions

Tags: transformer, design

Basically, I am supposed to obtain the equivalent magnetic circuit of a transformer, including the magnetizing inductance and the core resistance, based only on the core material and loss (which were given), and the core/winding dimensions which I have calculated.
I have already calculated the leakage inductance and winding resistance, but I am at a loss on how to do this without performing an open circuit test. Is there any way to estimate this analytically? Alternatively, is there any way I could do this in Simulink?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the reluctance of the core? Do you know how many turns?

Comment: You can estimate the inductance with a frequency generator with no load on the transformer.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes I know both.

Comment: @VoltageSpike In Simulink? How do i get the inductance?

Comment: What do you get when you divide turns squared by reluctance @AndréGuerreiro

Comment: Oh shit right, thank you @Andyaka

Comment: Do you want me to make a formal answer to your question @AndréGuerreiro

Comment: No sir, I was just being dumb! Thank you @Andyaka

Comment: Either you should make an answer or I should because this is how the site works. I will make an answer @AndréGuerreiro

Comment: How big of a transformer are we talking about? Really tiny ones may have 20% magnitizing current. Large grid-scale ones less than 1 %.

Answer (score 1):

> *How to estimate magnetizing inductance and core resistance of
> transformer based only on material properties and dimensions*

From a comment by me: Do you know the reluctance of the core? Do you know how many turns?

> *@Andyaka Yes I know both*

What do you get when you divide turns squared by reluctance @AndréGuerreiro

> *Oh shit right, thank you @Andyaka*

A longer answer can be provided if it is felt necessary.